# Getting the source marker of an on click event in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, markers

I create multiple `Marker`s in leaflet and bind an `on click` event handler to each of them, such as:

```
marker = L.marker(
        geoJsonPoint.geometry.coordinates,
        { icon: someIcon }
    ).bindPopup("<h3>" + someHeaderText + </h3>");

marker.on("click", someEventHandlerFunction);
```

In my `someEventHandlerFunction` I have the `event` as an argument, but how can I find out from *which particular marker* the function was called?

Clicking/expanding through the properties of the `event` doesn't seem to contain anything useful (or I may have missed it so far):

[image: event object properties]

I'd simply like to use something like below in the event handler:

```
function someEventHandler(event) {
    // Possibly have to cast this to marker
    let marker = event.<---what-could-go-here--->.source; 
}
```

Comment: Both `event.target` and `event.sourceTarget` point to your `marker` object.

Comment: Thank you, I passed the wanted property from my `marker` via the options when creating that marker: `L.marker(coordinates, { name: myName, myOtherProperty: "..." });` and can now access that in the event handler.